# write file (python) to S3 from databricks without using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks

I have my access key and security key for AWS but I would like to write the file in the S3 bucket without exposing my access key and security key in python code.

Comment: (a) the content of your question seems different from the title of your question, and (b) how do you expect your code to authenticate to s3 without access to your credentials?

Comment: I wonder if a [pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) would help you achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks, you can define [External locations | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-external-locations.html):

> An external location is a securable object that combines a storage path with a storage credential that authorizes access to that path.

Basically, you provide an S3 path to Databricks and give it an IAM Role. The S3 bucket can then be accessed via SQL/Spark simply by reference, without having to provide credentials and without having to use boto3.

For example:

```
select * from read_files('s3://bucket-name/folder/')
```

You can also create [Volumes | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-volumes.html):

> Volumes are Unity Catalog objects representing a logical volume of storage in a cloud object storage location. Volumes provide capabilities for accessing, storing, governing, and organizing files.

This gives a disk-like interface to an S3 bucket, again using stored credentials. Your code can then access the volume like this:

```
SELECT * FROM csv.`/Volumes/mycatalog/myschema/myexternalvolume/sample.csv`
```

If you are reading/writing files from Python, then the Volume gives you direct access to the S3 bucket without having to use boto3. You just refer to the Volume path (as shown above) as if it is a local disk.